# Why doesn't my state-list-drawable applied to an ImageView use the drawable for pressed-state when I touch the ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable, xml-drawable, statelistdrawable

I have my `ImageView` defined in XML like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state_list_drawable" />
```

The `button_state_list_drawable.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_state_drawable"
        android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled_state_drawable"
        android:state_enabled="true" />

</selector>
```

The `button_pressed_state_drawable.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <size android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp" />

    <padding android:left="25dp"
        android:right="25dp"
        android:top="25dp"
        android:bottom="25dp" />

    <stroke android:color="#fff"
        android:width="1dp" />

    <solid android:color="#1aafd0" />

</shape>
```

The `button_enabled_state_drawable.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <size android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp" />

    <padding android:left="25dp"
        android:right="25dp"
        android:top="25dp"
        android:bottom="25dp" />

    <stroke android:color="#fff"
        android:width="1dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

</shape>
```

The problem is that when I click/touch the `ImageView`, the `button_pressed_state_drawable` does not seem to be used, i.e. I can't see the `<solid android:color="#1aafd0" />` in action (which is basically the only difference between the two drawables), i.e the background color is still transparent instead of changing to blue. Where am I messing up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your `ImageView` is not `clickable`.

Try to make it clickable by using `ImageView.setClicked(true)`.

or

```
        android:clickable="true"
```

Also make sure that your `image resource` is not covered your background.

This is what i've done which works fine.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state_list_drawable"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

Comment: Thank You buddy. Not setting this single attribute gave me headache.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_state_drawable"
    android:state_pressed="true" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled_state_drawable"
    android:state_enabled="true" />
```

A button can be both "pressed" and "enabled." Try removing android:state_enabled="true" from the 2nd item.